# Error 403 (Forbidden) at user's encrypted public_html directory

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-10.10

I have a clean installation of Ubuntu 10.10 for my new workstation.

I used tasksel to install lamp-server.

I then enabled userdir module using a2enmod utility.

that loads a conf file `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/userdir.conf`

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
    UserDir disabled root

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            AllowOverride All
            Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
                            Allow from all
                            Order allow,deny
            <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Limit>
            <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Deny from all
            </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

I commented all those recommended lines in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.conf`

```
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_value engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

I have also `chmod -R 755 public_html` and `chgrp -R www-data public_html`

And after all this setup

`http://localhost/~shoaib` results...

*You don't have permission to access /~shoaib on this server.*

**WHAT I AM MISSING HERE????**

Comment: should be on serverfault I guess. Did you restart apache btw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://ohioloco.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7543223

This entry seems to conclude it happens if you have an encrypted home directory.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your user's home folder permission to allow others to execute in it.

```
chmod o+x /home/$user
```

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/585212